# How to sort multicolumn ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have an arraylist as follows :

```
String[] s = {"John","Mary","Jane"};
double[] d = {18,21,34};

ArrayList<HashMap<String, CharSequence>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, CharSequence>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   HashMap<String, CharSequence> temp = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
   temp.put("col1", s[i]);
   temp.put("col2", Double.toString(d[i]));
   list1.add(temp);
}
```

If I want to sort any column in the list, how to do it? thank you.

infomation added :

I have try to write a comparator, but it can only sort for the first column. I don't know how to sort the second column.

```
Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<HashMap<String, CharSequence>>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(HashMap<String, CharSequence> s1, HashMap<String, CharSequence> s2)
   {
      return  s1.toString().compareTo(s2.toString());
   }
});
```

Information added :

I have tried to modify the return statement, but it gets Nullpointer Exception :

```
return  s1.get(1).toString().compareTo(s2.get(1).toString());
```

Information added :

Thank you all. It seems that the HashMap has no indexer and caused NullPointer Exception, now the problem is solved by using column name:

```
return  s1.get("col2").toString().compareTo(s2.get("col2").toString());
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little better? Do you want to sort it by `s` or by `d`? You want to store the sorted column in a new variable, or you want to modify the `ArrayList list1`?

Comment: Start by writing a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)... and maybe use `<String, Double>`.

Comment: I mean either s or d as needed.

Comment: I know I have to write a comparator, but I don't know how to write it and use it in code. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: I have added a comparator, please see above.

Comment: Thank you all, the probelm is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to sort according to your string `s`

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
                 int returned = sequence.indexOf(key1) - sequence.indexOf(key2);
   //.indexOf(key1) returns the index of the first character of the String
                 if(returned < 0){ 
                         // then it is sorted; 
                   returned 1;
                 }

                 else{
                     returned = -1;}

                 return returned;
                }
         };
         Map<String,Double> lhm = new TreeMap<String,Double>(comparator);
```

This is not the solution for your problem but you can go by this way.

Comment: Thank you, I have just added a comparator. My problem is how to sort the second column or how to let the comparator knows which column have to be sorted.

Comment: `TreeMap` will give you the sorted order of keys and what is the need of sorting your second column?

Comment: It is just an example, suppose the first column is "Name" and second column is "age", we can sort either Name or Age. I don't know what is TreeMap, it is new to me.